# Where is the rear wheel quick-release mechanism on my bike?

Tags: wheels, rear-wheel, quick-release

Below are two pictures of my road bike's rear wheel (from the left and the right-hand side). As you can easily notice the tire is flat, and I suspect the tube needs to be changed since it's an old bike.

So I need to remove the rear wheel first, but all the videos on Youtube that show you how to do that work on a quick-release mechanism (which is quite straightforward).

I wonder how I can remove the wheel in my case (and what's the name of this model of release)?

[image: rear wheel 1]

[image: rear wheel 2]

Comment: This is a basic quick release lever, flip the lever portion in the first image the opposite direction which should loosen in a bit, then you can hold the knob in the second image and spin the lever in the first image to loosen it further, after than it should just slip out.

Comment: The lever appears to be underneat the chainstay in the first picture.

Comment: On the left side, by the disc brakes.

Comment: Fixed title as the OP can't find the quickrelease rather than it not existing.

Comment: Ps. Given the type of tubing, rear triangle configuration, and rack mounting holes, I'd call your bike either a "touring bike" or "cargo bike" but not a "road bike" - which tend toward racing configurations.

Comment: @RoboKaren This is the model I have [Norco Threshold A3 2013](http://www.thebikelist.co.uk/norco/threshold-a3-disc-2013)

Comment: Just so you know - its totally possible to patch a tube without removing the wheel from the bike.  Can be a bit fiddly around the brakes, but still eminently achievable.   Replacing the tube or tyre, that needs the wheel to come off completely.

Comment: Have you tried just inflating it?   It would be common for a bike tyre to loose air over time.  Its possible there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Criggie I've confirmed this morning that the tube is punctured (I saw bubbles coming from a tiny hole in it, when I put it inside a water bucket). It was really tricky to remove the tube (the tire is too tight around the rim), I don't think I would have been able to remove it with taking off the tire.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a standard quick release mechanism simply grab the lever indicated below and flip it the opposite direction (green arrow). At which point it should loosen up a bit, then you can spin it around to the left to unscrew it further. You do not have to take it all the way out, just loosen it enough to be able to slide the wheel out. You can also hold onto the silver knob in your second picture to help unscrew it, that is how you adjust the clamping force of the lever.

When you have your wheel out to repair, be sure not to pull the brake lever as this will cause issues with your brake caliper as it will try and clamp down on the rotor which will not be there.

When reinstalling be sure to pay attention to the rotor as they can sometimes be tricky to line up with the slot in the brake caliper.

Also when closing the QR you should need to apply force from roughly the half closed position. Not closing the QR tightly enough, or not fully closed may cause it to open at an inopportune time resulting in possible injury.Thanks to @Alex for this addition.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't need to unscrew the rear QR as there are no lawyer lips on the rear dropout. Just need to ensure the chain is on the smallest cog and the derailleur is pulled out of the way and the rear wheel should drop out.

Comment: Should add that to close the QR lever again, make sure that you apply force from when the lever is about half-way closed. Not closing the QR tightly or not closing it completely can lead to the wheel detaching at an inopportune moment.

Comment: @Rider_X - I generally find it necessary to unscrew the QR a turn or two on most bikes.  (And of course then screw it in a bit before flipping the QR lever to lock it.  It should take some effort to "close" the QR lever.)

Comment: @Alex i added in your suggestion. Thanks! - I am the same way Daniel, they usual require 1 or two spins for me with or without lawyer lips.

Comment: @Rider_X: while you're probably right, I do see lawyer lips on rear dropouts occasionally, usually on just barely above BSO grade frames.